# presentViewController in full screen mode on iPhone X

Tags: objective-c, ios11, iphone-x

As you know there are no problems when we present a view controller with the full-screen option before:

```
modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

However, on iPhone X, it will be overlapped by the top-notch and bottom bar.
Do you have any solution for that without customizing presenting controller's (from a static library) subviews?

Thank you!

Comment: Watch the video.  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/201/

Comment: Seem still needs to update the UI of the being presenting controller. But it is a static library. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a trick to prevent the issues with iPhone X without modifying the presenting controller (Controller A) from a static library like this:

1. Create a new controller (Controller B) add a subview which
   applies the auto layout to the safeAreaLayoutGuide.
2. Init Controller A of the static library inside Controller B, the add
       Controller A's view to Controller B's subview.
3. Present Controller B instead of direct present Controller A

Comment: "add Controller A's view to Controller B's subview" But you must not _just_ add it. There is a proper "dance" to make controller A the _child_ of controller B, establishing a parent-child relationship between them. You _must_ do that "dance" correctly.

Comment: This solution will not work if you doing thing programatically for a third party library.

Answer (score 1):

Check you bottom constraint. You have to connect view inside your controller to the view (not bottom layout guide). That's it.